# for loop doesn't process all values

Tags: c#, for-loop, nested-function

I have a set of nested functions which I will use in the `for-loop`. But `for-loop` doesn't process all the values.

Snippet below:

```
.....
.....
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
 A();
}
.....
....

A()
{
 for(j=0;j<5;j++)
 {
  B();
  if j false then return;
 }
 return;
}

B()
{
 for(k=0;k<5;k++)
 {
  A();
  if k false then return;
 }
 return;
}
```

In above code, `for-loop` in `B()` does not take all values, it just takes a single value and
then stops the loop. What is the problem in `B()`'s for loop? How can I process the all values?

Comment: Both methods are nested in each other, you know that won't end well.

Comment: This code makes a DeadLock, because A() always call at least one time B()-> B() calls at least one time A()-> A() calls at least one time A()... and its never ends. CHange your code because is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

In the first iteration of the first loop `A()` is called. In the first iteration of that loop `B()` is called. In the first iteration of `B`'s lop `A()` is called. Which calls `B()` which calls `A()` … until the stack overflows.

You have created a pair of mutually recursive functions without any condition to bottom out (stop) the recursion.

Removing the loops from `A` and `B`

```
A() {
  B();
}
B() {
  A();
}
```

more directly shows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You think that it is not taking the second value. But actually it will be throwing exception of type. **stackoverflow**.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "stops the loop" - I would assume that this throws an exception, or something?

Look at it; The calls are like:

```
Call A() Five times each time..
   calling B() five times, each time...
       calling A() five times...                 
           calling B() five times, each time...
               calling A() five times... 
                   etc.. (which goes back to the top)
```

That will recurse (call itself "inwards" repeatedly) until you run out of memory, and then crash and throw a `StackOverflowException`.

Note: Only the first call in each loop will be called, since each time such a call is made, a new loop will be started. That is probably why it seems to you that only the first value is processed.